# Posting long and lat on database

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps-api-3

I am having some problems with my current code.

I am not able to receive the results of the longitude and latitude from the address text field. Once I receive that I want to put the longitude and latitude into my database. I am not sure if that is possible because the value that it is checking(address) is in the form tag.

Any input would help... thanks

```js
function initialize() {
  var address = (document.getElementById('address'));
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(address);
  autocomplete.setTypes(['geocode']);
  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (!place.geometry) {
      return;
    }

    var address = '';
    if (place.address_components) {
      address = [
        (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''), (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''), (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
      ].join(' ');
    }
  });
}

function codeAddress() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': address
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

      alert("Latitude: " + results[0].geometry.location.lat() + "Longitude: " + results[0].geometry.location.lng());
    } else {
      alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
<form method="post" action="formconnect.php" ;>

  <h2>Add new location</h2>
  <p>Please add your company information within this form</p>


  Name:
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <br>Hours:
  <input type="text" name="hours">
  <br>Baseball:
  <select name="baseball">
    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
    <option value="Coming Soon">Coming Soon</option>
  </select>
  <br>Basketball:
  <select name="basketball">
    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
    <option value="Coming Soon">Coming Soon</option>
  </select>
  <br>Hockey:
  <select name="hockey">
    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
    <option value="Coming Soon">Coming Soon</option>
  </select>
  <br>Golf:
  <select name="golf">
    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
    <option value="Coming Soon">Coming Soon</option>
  </select>
  <br>Soccer:
  <select name="soccer">
    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
    <option value="Coming Soon">Coming Soon</option>
  </select>
  <br>Address:
  <input type="text" name="address">
  <br>
  <input type='hidden' value='' name='lat' />
  <input type='hidden' value='' name='lng' />
  </br>
  </br>

  <input onClick="codeAddress()" type="submit"></input>



</form>
```

Here is the formconnect.php too

```
$sql="INSERT INTO markers (name, hours, baseball, basketball, hockey, golf, soccer, address, lat, lng)
VALUES
('$_POST[name]','$_POST[hours]','$_POST[baseball]','$_POST[basketball]','$_POST[hockey]','$_POST[golf]','$_POST[soccer]','$_POST[address]','$_POST[lat]','$_POST[lng]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "one record added";
mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: looks like a  pure js issue ?

Comment: I was able to run the script with just address and no posting to DB and it worked great. So I assume that the JS is good

Comment: am i missing seeing any code to add db?

Comment: It is in the form tag

Comment: we need to see formconnect.php

Comment: It will post everything else besides the lat and lng I will add on to it

Comment: if you echo `$sql` does it contain the data you expect.

Comment: Yes it contains all the information I entered except for lng and lat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some subtle errors in your code

1. You did not specify code that will give the longitude and latitude fields their values. I know you are getting the values from google, but there is nowhere you are passing those values to your fields. We will see what we can do about that.

One in your html, give id to each of the fields you want to reference through getElementById(), including the form itself. Like so ( I am leaving out other fields since they are unaffected),

```
    <form method="post" action="formconnect.php" id="form1">
    .
    .
    .
    <input type="text" name="address" id="address" />

   <input type='hidden' value='' name='lat' id="lat" />

   <input type='hidden' value='' name='lng' id="lng" />
```

Let us also change the submit button to  tag this has nothing to do with the problem here. Just forthe sake of html5 like so,

```
    <button onClick="codeAddress()" type="button" name="upload" >SUBMIT</button>
```

Changing the type of the button to 'button' instead of 'submit' makes sure the form does not get submitted until you do so in the code.

Now the JS,

```
    <script>

    var codeAddress = function () {

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    var address = document.getElementById("address").value;

    geocoder.geocode(
        {'address': address}, 

        function (results, status) {

           if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

               document.getElementById("lat").value = results[0].geometry.location.lat();

               document.getElementById("lng").value = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

               document.getElementById("form1").submit();

          }else{

            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status );
          }
       });
    };

    </script>
```

Notice that the code that gives values to the latitude and longitude fields have been move to within the callback, specifically when the result is 'OK'. The form submission also is move there to ensure the form only gets submitted when the response from google is 'OK'

2. Again I guess the other function 'initialize' implements autocomplete. I changed the place where you call it. I just call it immediately it is created like so,

   ```
      var initialize = function() {

          var address = (document.getElementById('address'));

          var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(address);

          autocomplete.setTypes(['geocode']);

          google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {

             var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

             if (!place.geometry) {
               return;
             }

             var address = '';

             if (place.address_components) { address = [
                (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''), (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''), (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
               ].join(' ');
             }
          });
     }();
   ```

Notice the () operator at the end of the function ? That is what calls it immediately after declaration. Try this and let's see how things go.

Comment: I used your code. But when I click SUBMIT it does nothing. Look at it above.

Comment: You see, it's not **my** code. It's **your** code. I just made very little modifications. Things like this go beyond copying and pasting codes. Maybe we should chat rather than post comments back and forth. However, to address your point in the immediate, study the form, make changes **only** to these five line above. Again, for the JS, make sure the two functions above are within `<script> </script>` ; then move your script from head to just before `</body>` . As for the line that references google geolocation, it should be within `<head></head>` or, better still, before your own `<script>`.

Comment: Stephen, Thank you. I did not realize I needed to take it out of the <head>

Answer (score 0):

Replace submit type input with a button

```
<button onClick="codeAddress()">submit</button>
```

Give your form a name

```
<form method="post" action="formconnect.php" name="form1">
```

Give your hidden inputs IDs

```
<input type='hidden' value='' name='lat' id='lat'>
<input type='hidden' value='' name='lng' id='lng'>
```

Use your function to set the value of the hidden values and submit the form

```
function codeAddress() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': address
    }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            var lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

        } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });

    alert("Latitude: " + results[0].geometry.location.lat() + "Longitude: " + results[0].geometry.location.lng());
    document.getElementById("lat").value = lat;
    document.getElementById("lng").value = lng;
    document.getElementById("form1").submit();
}
```

Comment: You also have a </input> and semicolon in <form>

Comment: Still not posting the coordinates. I removed the semicolon, thanks for spotting that.

Comment: Do you get the alert? As the JS doesn't set the field values as appears.

Comment: No alert either. Just shows the echo call when I hit submit.

Comment: document.getElementById("lat").value = results[0].geometry.location.lat();

Comment: Do I place that outside the function?

Comment: Needs to be before the submit. There is an issue if you are not getting the alerts as they are prior to the submit. I editted the answer to reflect.

Comment: Updated answer to move alerts outside the geocode functon